# Is there a replacement for variant data type in .NET?

Tags: .net, types, variant, delphi-prism

I would like to know if there is a variant data type in Delphi prism.

I am converting a Delphi win32 application for Delphi Prism .NET environment.

Comment: `object` can represent "all types", but it won't allow invoking methods will-nilly. `dynamic` (in .NET4) can also represent "all types", but it will allow invoking methods willy-nilly. Ideally though, a correct strong type is chosen/used, however. (I can't say I missing "variant" data types...)

Comment: @pst, I would have posted that as an answer :-)

Comment: I don't think there's a specific type that replaces it, but `object` should work for `variant`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest thing is `Object` as all types derive from it. This is not a great solution though.

With .NET 4.0 the [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) keyword was introduced that may be closer to what you are looking for.

A direct analogue does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I think variant data types in C++/COM are roughly equivalent to the object type in C#. The Wikipedia article confirms this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type in the fourth paragraph